# Facebook page like count by php

Tags: php, facebook

I am try to get page like count by the link

```
 echo file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/hostbdfree?fields=fan_count&access_token=$token");
```

But Here i show error (#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active accounts due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform

I change many app but same error show

also i try Facebook SDK but same error show

how i solve the error please give me Suggestion .

Comment: It’s a problem with the account you are using to contact fb

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/

Answer (score 0):

> Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active accounts

Get an active account with Facebook.

Comment: But my Account active. however how check my account that not active ?

Comment: Facebook tells you otherwise. Go check with Facebook here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/

Comment: I check here with another  fb account but same problem plz give me soluation